# New Boston Android : Getting Null Pointer Exception in Accelerate (Sensor Management)

Tags: android, android-sensors

i m a newbie to android and following new boston android series ,and got stuck here.
Getting null pointer exception in sensor management app and app crashing in my class **Accelerate.**
while testing on real device.

my code :

```
package com.ss;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Accelerate extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    float x, y, sensorX, sensorY;
    Bitmap ball;
    SensorManager sm;
    MyBringBackSurface ourSurfaceView;

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sm.unregisterListener(this);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent e) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(16);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        sensorX = e.values[0]; // return sensor events of x axis 
        sensorY = e.values[1];
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            setContentView(ourSurfaceView);
            sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
            if (sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).size() != 0) {
                Sensor s = sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0);
                sm.registerListener(this, s, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            }
            ball = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ball);
            x = y = sensorX = sensorY = 0;
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(new MyBringBackSurface(this));
            ourSurfaceView.resume();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("ERROR");
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            String error = "IDHAR AYA HAI "+e.toString();
            tv.setText(error);
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();
        }
    }

    public class MyBringBackSurface extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

        SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
        Thread ourThread = null;
        Boolean isRunning = false;

        public MyBringBackSurface(Context context) {
            super(context);
            ourHolder = getHolder();

        }

        public void pause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            isRunning = false;
            while (true) {
                Log.v("message", "Exceptino not");
                try {
                    ourThread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.v("message", "Exceptino", e);
                }
                break;
            }
            ourThread = null;
        }

        public void resume() {
            isRunning = true;
            ourThread = new Thread(this);
            ourThread.start();
            Log.v("message", "started thread");
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.v("messge", isRunning.toString());
            try {
                Canvas canvas;
                while (isRunning) {
                    if (!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
                        continue;
                    canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
                    canvas.drawRGB(02, 02, 150);
                    float centerX = canvas.getWidth() / 2;
                    float centerY = canvas.getHeight() / 2;
                    canvas.drawBitmap(ball, centerX + sensorX * 20, centerY
                            + sensorY * 20, null);
                    ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    Log.v("message", "run startede");
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("mytag", "mymessage", ex);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Log cat

```
03-07 11:06:27.957: D/AndroidRuntime(749): Shutting down VM
03-07 11:06:27.967: W/dalvikvm(749): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
03-07 11:06:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(749): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 11:06:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(749): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.ss/com.ss.Accelerate} did not call through to super.onCreate()
03-07 11:06:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
03-07 11:06:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-07 11:06:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-07 11:06:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-07 11:06:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-07 11:06:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-07 11:06:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-07 11:06:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 11:06:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-07 11:06:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-07 11:06:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-07 11:06:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 11:06:31.887: I/Process(749): Sending signal. PID: 749 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace.  We are guessing without it.

Comment: i m testing on real device ...with bluetooth...so no stack trace

Comment: Ironic username is ironic

Comment: So connect it with USB or ADB WifI.  No stack trace, no fix!

Comment: i m using moto e for testing on win 8 .and USB for moto e doesnt support win 8.as told by moto customer care..:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
03-07 11:06:28.007: E/AndroidRuntime(749): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.ss/com.ss.Accelerate} did not call through to super.onCreate()
```

Try calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` first in your `onCreate()` Method in the `Accelerate` Class.

Comment: I think your problem is solved and you have another problem now because before you had a `SuperNotCalledException`. You should raise a new question.